# Responsive issue: Responsive is not working properly in iphone

Tags: iphone, css

After completing responsive for @media screen and (max-width:320px){ code } and @media screen and (max-width:480px){ code } that is for iphone portrait and landscape, the design works perfectly in pc browsers but the design seems small that is for 320px it is showing 160 to the left screen of the iphone portrait.

Answer (score 0):

add following meta tag in your head tag

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

and more thing
Internet Explorer 8 or older doesn't support media query. You can use media-queries.js or respond.js to add media query support in IE.

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://css3-mediaqueries-js.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/css3-mediaqueries.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
```

Comment: i have tried this code. but after that also it is not working properly.

Comment: @media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) { /* STYLES GO HERE */}  use this one. Are you beginner for responsive website?

Comment: Let me known if you have any query.

Comment: i know only to use media screen and (max-width:320px) and media screen and (max-width:480px) separately. How to use media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px)?? what it means??

Comment: http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/  here is the reference link please first check it out , you can get more idea..

Comment: http://www.andreasnorman.com/css-media-queries-for-mobile-devices/ check out this one is also.

Comment: can you please give me an example for this??

Comment: @media screen and (max-width:480px){ 
#container {
    width: 470px;
}
#menu {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 425px;
}

#header {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0 auto;
    min-height: 250px;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
.columns > .content {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 420px;
}}

Comment: @media screen and (max-width:320px){ 

#container {
    width: 310px;
}
#menu {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 290px;
}
#menu {
    float: none;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 290px;
}

.columns {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

.columns > .content {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    width: 280px;
}}

Answer (score 0):

@user2582867 :please use following code :

```
@media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) 
and (max-device-width : 480px) {

#container { width: 310px!important; }
#menu { float: none!important; padding-left: 10px!important; padding-right: 10px!important; text-align: center!important; width: 290px!important; }
#menu { float: none!important; padding-left: 10px!important; padding-right: 10px!important; text-align: center!important; width: 290px!important; } 
.columns { background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent!important; padding-left: 5px!important; padding-right: 5px!important; } 
.columns > .content { float: left!important; margin-left: 15px!important; width: 280px!important; }
}
```

Comment: when trying with my old one and checking it in a responsive checker it works very very fine. but while seeing in iphone it does not same as in responsive checker.. it is very very small.. although i done all your suggestions.. but still finding the same issue..

Comment: oh. i have tried a lot.. i dont know why it happens.. i have done lot of designs previously. Did not face such an issue. Struggling this issue with 4 days. Didnot get any solutions yet. But thank you for your effort. I learned few more things by your suggestions. Thank you once again..

Comment: i am doing this in wordpress. I found out the issue. When i installing some plugins the responsive is collapsed. Why it happens. Do you have any idea.

Comment: Sorry,no idea about WordPress responsive.